# Failed to implement google plus authentication in android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus-signin

I have added all required configurations in my code to apply google plus authentication. Unfortunately the authentication process is returning `handleSignInResult:false` every time. I am listing all steps that I did to configure my project for google plus authentication.

In project level gradle I added...

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

and in the app level gradle I added

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my server client id looks like `xxxxxxx-n7i6lyyyyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com` and I found it from **OAuth 2.0 client IDs**

```
Web client 1    Mar 12, 2016    Web application     xxxxxxx-n7i6lyyyyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Also I added **google-services.json** in the app directory of my project which is `/app`

and the following permission are added to the project manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Every time it is going to `onConnectionFailed` method and returning `handleSignInResult:false`

```
@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }
```

My project is using gradle-2.10 by default. So, I am using gms:play-services:8.3.0 instead of gms:play-services:8.4.0.

Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same problem then i updated my code given below also available on some demos

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {

            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    }


/**
 * Method to resolve any sign in errors
 * */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

and also do this

```
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

try this if you have not done this

and also check have you call onActivityResult method that is must

Comment: what are mIntentInProgress and mSignInClicked?

Comment: both are boolean variables.

Comment: no - didn't work for me. Actually ConnectionResult is false.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/    
check this link what you are missing

Comment: you are testing this in physical device or in emulator.. and if device then are u logined with any google account or not?

Comment: yes testing with real device and already logged in. Can you please tell me how to enable deep linking?

Comment: deep linking is not requires just create a client api key on google console